# How do I Mock GPS route in 2018?

Tags: android, gps

This question is a two fold one i.e. it will be of two parts.

We are developing an traffic event app, where based on event X, driver Y gets information. Quick example, McDonalds pays us to send a discount code for free coffee to all drivers that pass their restaurants between 4-6 in the morning if they are driving under the speed limit.

As one can imagine, being able to test this without going for a ride to the nearest McDonalds is a great 'feature' for out developers.

What we used so far is an app called **Lockito**. This app had 3 basic features.

1. Being able to **define** a route between A and B
2. Being able to **save** this route for future use
3. Being able to simulate your location moving on the route with **predefined speed**.

*Question part 1*:

**Have Google updated their terms and conditions on Google play store?**
Basically the [Lockito App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=en) located here was deleted, I was wondering why? Has something in Android Pie's SDK forbid developers from mocking gps routes?

*Question part 2:*

**In 2018, if I as a Android developer, need to fulfill the 3 basic features described above for GPS route mocking, what app/simulator/inbuild tool do I need to use?**

Now I have [stackoverflow-ed this question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mocking%20gps%20route) and there is basically no recent answer to it. As the latest being from 2015.
I found 2 directions of how to tackle the problem:

1. Use an app from Play Store -- I cant find one that works paid or free one
2. Use KML format to simulate GPS location routes in Android emulator -- KML doesnt support defining speed

So what do other developers do?

Comment: I've used [Mock Locations](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gavrikov.mocklocations). It allows saving routes and setting the speed. You create routes either "free hand" or based on Google Map street data.

Answer (score 0):

You can still get Lockito from an alternative source such as apkpure.com. I didn't test if it was legit, but there are other sources to install Lockito from other than the Play Store.

Unfortunately Lockito stopped working properly in my case. I only get 'can't retrieve itinerary over query limit' errors and cannot create a route anymore. I'm also looking for another solution than Lockito but can't find any that work the same way Lockito did.

**UPDATE:** As of last week there seems to have been an update on Lockito. It's available again in the play store and it's working correctly again.

Comment: I have also experienced this issue if I create an itinerary between random points in the map. But, as a workaound, if I'm really careful to point the start and stop marker on an actual road the problem seem to appear less frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Was waiting for those features too, finally the latest release of Android Studio 4 and his new Emulator update 10/23/2019 answer to two of your questions and a part of the third one. 
Start your emulator and go to emulator parameters ... > in "Routes" tab you can 
(1) choose two points on the map from/to (2) save them, and start a new route with 5 predefined playback speeds that can go to more than 1000km/h, but till now you cant chose an exact speed, the speed is still wired sometimes go too fast and don't slow down when i choose 1X .. hope Google fix that in the official realize of Android Studio 4.

https://youtu.be/XPMrnR1_Biw?t=1746